# Plotly: How to represent coded data on a graph?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Good people, I have this data which I do what to represent on a plot

```
import pandas as pd 

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital','Nick hospital', 'Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital','Krish hospital'], 
        'NAR_forms_used':[2, 1,2, 2, 2,3]
       } 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the output. 
df
```

Now when collecting my data there are these forms we use called NAR form, which we share per hospital. Now the data collection tool is coded in that when NAR form is used, its coded 1 and when it's not used then it's coded 2 and finally when the form was submitted to the data clerk empty its coded 3. I want to represent these results on a graph where when the column for **NAR_forms_used** has this code which *1 is for yes*, *2 is for No* and *3 is for empty*. How can I represent this data on a plot per hospital?

I tried this

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(
        x = df['Name'],
        y = df['NAR_forms_used']
                    )],
    layout=go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
        yaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
    )
)

fig.show()
```

But the results is not what I want, How can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question with plotly and not gotten a plotly answer yet, here's how I would do it:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital','Nick hospital', 'Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital','Krish hospital'], 
        'NAR_forms_used':[2, 1,2, 2, 2,3]
       } 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get counts per NAR type
df_nar=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Name')['NAR_forms_used'].value_counts())
df_nar=df_nar.rename({'NAR_forms_used': 'NAR count'}, axis='columns')
df_nar=df_nar.reset_index()

# Manage NAR types (who knows, there may be more types with time?)
nars = df_nar['NAR_forms_used'].unique()
nars = nars.tolist()
nars.sort(reverse=False)

# set up plotly figure
fig = go.Figure()

# add one trace per NAR type and show counts per hospital
for nar in nars:

    # subset dataframe by NAR type
    df_ply=df_nar[df_nar['NAR_forms_used']==nar]

    # add trace
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_ply['Name'], y=df_ply['NAR count'], name='NAR Type='+str(nar)))

# make the figure a bit more presentable

fig.update_layout(title='NAR per hospital',
                  yaxis=dict(title='<i>count of NAR types</i>'),
                  xaxis=dict(title='<i>Hospital</i>',
                            )
                 )


fig.show()
```

As you probably know, there is no NAR type 3 for Nick Hospital and no NAR type 1 for Krish Hospital, so that's why the figure might seem a little strange at first glance. It all makes sense when you add some more data to your sample:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital','Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital', 'Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital','Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital'], 
        'NAR_forms_used':[3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1]
       } 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get counts per NAR type
df_nar=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Name')['NAR_forms_used'].value_counts())
df_nar=df_nar.rename({'NAR_forms_used': 'NAR count'}, axis='columns')
df_nar=df_nar.reset_index()

# Manage NAR types (who knows, there may be more types with time?)
nars = df_nar['NAR_forms_used'].unique()
nars = nars.tolist()
nars.sort(reverse=False)

# set up plotly figure
fig = go.Figure()

# add one trace per NAR type and show counts per hospital
for nar in nars:

    # subset dataframe by NAR type
    df_ply=df_nar[df_nar['NAR_forms_used']==nar]

    # add trace
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_ply['Name'], y=df_ply['NAR count'], name='NAR Type='+str(nar)))

# make the figure a bit more presentable

fig.update_layout(title='NAR per hospital',
                  yaxis=dict(title='<i>count of NAR types</i>'),
                  xaxis=dict(title='<i>Hospital</i>',
                            )
                 )


fig.show()
```

Comment: How can I possibly add this to plotly-dash app  and plotly per hospital differently, probably by having a dropdown of hospitals

Answer (score 0):

If you need to plot the number of `NAR_forms_used` for each hospital I suggest you to use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). Here's a snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# intialise data of lists and create DataFrame  
data = {'Name':np.random.choice(['Nick hospital', 'Krish hospital'], size=80), 
        'NAR_forms_used':np.random.choice([1,2,3], size=80)} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df_to_plot = (df.groupby('Name')['NAR_forms_used']
              .value_counts()
              .to_frame()
              .rename({'NAR_forms_used': 'NAR_forms_count'}, axis='columns')
              .reset_index())

sns.barplot(data=df_to_plot, x='Name', y='NAR_forms_count', hue='NAR_forms_used')
```

[image]